# SSRS Field Data Based On Other Field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field on an SSRS report running this expression:

```
=First(Fields!Record_Notes.Value)
```

I need this to only display data from the Record_Notes field if another field (Note_Service_Index) on this same table has a specific value.

I'm very new to SSRS and am rusty in terms of VB language.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSRS 2008 **R2** and not just plain '08, check out the Lookup/LookupSet/MultiLookup functions:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx

Comment: I believe the problem might be that the Note_Service_Index field from the table I am referencing is not included in the Datasheet scope. Is that something the Lookup can handle or will I need to figure out how to add this column to the Datasheet scope?

Comment: Yes, in fact any aggregate function, and many other functions, can accept an optional scope parameter - in this case, the name of your dataset.  From your original example, this would look like:  =First(Fields!Record_Notes.Value, "DataSetName").  The lookup functions can be used if you need to fetch data from one set for use within a different set.

Comment: I might be a bit confused on your response. I have tried going to the existing datasheet properties and adding a queried field, but once it is added to the datasheet if I pull the query out to a notepad and search for Note_Service_Index, it appears that it doesn't update the query. Ideally I need it to works something like this:

IF Fields!Note_Service_Index.Value = "scope" THEN Fields!Record_Notes.Value Else NULL

I'm not sure how to write that into SSRS given that the Note_Service_Index isn't part of the datasheet scope.

Comment: So, your question and my advice have been about SSRS - so I'm not sure why you're trying this in a query?  As for the logic you're looking for, the IIF statements syntax is IIF(Condition, DoWhenTrue, DoWhenFalse), so the expression that you'd want to use in your SSRS RDL for that logic would be =IIF(Fields!Note_Service_Index.Value = "scope", Fields!Record_Notes.Value, nothing)

Comment: I've tried that. I don't get any errors on the report when I run it or save it, but even when I know that there is a value in the column Note_service_Index, instead of getting the corresponding row's Record_Notes value, I get a blank. That I think, seems to be my main problem. The IIF statement syntax works, but isn't returning any kind of data.

Comment: What value is coming out of note_service_index?  SSRS comparisons are case-sensitive, do you perhaps need to case the value first?

Comment: The Note_Service_Index value is scope, all lowercase. It is the same in the IIF statement.